# Inside a child table how to change a foreign key while updating a record?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables . Based on the requirement I have to update the foreign key while updating the child record.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

1. Set foreign key to NULL.
2. Update primary key.
3. Update foreign key again.